# Find out if no items in a list are keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this list:

```
source = ['sourceid', 'SubSourcePontiflex', 'acq_source', 'OptInSource', 'source',
      'SourceID', 'Sub-Source', 'SubSource', 'LeadSource_295', 'Source',
      'SourceCode', 'source_code', 'SourceSubID']
```

I am iterating over XML in python to create a dictionary for each child node. The dictionary varies in length and keys with each iteration. Sometimes the dictionary will contain a key that is also an item in this list. Sometimes it wont. What I want to be able to do is, if a key in the dictionary is also an item in this list then append the value to a new list. If none of the keys in the dictionary are in list source, I'd like to append a default value. I'm really having a brain block on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the `in` keyword to check for membership of some key in a dictionary.

The following example will print `[3, 1]` since 3 and 1 are keys in the dictionary and also elements of the list.

```
someList = [8, 9, 7, 3, 1]
someDict = {1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5, 5:6}
intersection = [i for i in someList if i in someDict]
print(intersection)
```

You can just check if this `intersection` list is empty at every iteration. If the list is empty then you know that no items in the list are keys in the dictionary.

Comment: This was a very elegant and easy solution. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

```
in_source_and_dict = set(mydict.keys()).intersection(set(source))
in_dict_not_source = set(mydict.keys()) - set(source)
in_source_not_dict = set(source) - set(mydict.keys())
```

Iterate over the result of which one you want. In this case I guess you'll want to iterate over `in_source_not_dict` to provide default values.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, you can perform set operations directly on the object returned by `dict.keys()`:

```
in_source_and_dict = mydict.keys() & source
in_dict_not_source = mydict.keys() - source
in_source_not_dict = source - mydict.keys()
```

This will also work in Python 2.7 if you replace `.keys()` by `.viewkeys()`.

Comment: This almost works, but `source` is a list. You have to make a set out of it to use the operator versions of set operations.

Comment: @user2357112: You are wrong.  The list will implicitly be converted if necessary, and doing the conversion explicitly just adds unnecessary overhead (and visual clutter).

Comment: What the - huh. Apparently the rules are different for dict views and sets. `set([1]) & [1]` raises a `TypeError`, but `{1:2}.viewkeys() & [1]` gives `set([1])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict = { some values }
values = []
for s in sources:
    if my_dict.get(s):
        values += [s]
if not values:
    values += [default]
```

You can loop through the sources array and see if there is a value for that source in the dictionary.  If there is, append it to values.  After that loop, if values is empty, append the default vaule.

Note, if you have a key, value pair in your dictionary (val, None) then you will not append the None value to the end of the list.  If that is an issue you will probably not want to use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `any()` function

```
dict = {...}
keys = [...]
if not any(key in dict for key in keys):
    # no keys here
```

Equivalently, with `all()` (DeMorgan's laws):

```
if all(key not in dict for key in keys):
    # no keys here
```